# Controller Action won't bind JSON ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Every time I post to my Action, my `ViewModel` is not null, but all the values inside always are.

Where I have `console.log`, I can see perfect JSON being output to the console.

Any ideas?

Action:

```
public ActionResult Add(MyViewModel model)
{
//stuff
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var model = @Html.Raw(Viewbag.MyJSON);

var viewModelDetails = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

this.addData = function() {
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModelDetails);
console.log(data);
$.post("/user/add", data, function(result){
//stuff
});
}
</script>
```

Model

```
public  MyViewModel()
{
Game Game{get;set;}
}
```

EDIT:

WOW, I feel dumb, I had `private set`, so thats what it wasn't getting bound.

Comment: Can you post the JSON for `data` is after you call `ko.toJSON`?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$.post("/user/add", data, function(result){
//stuff
}, dataType: json);
```

What I've had happen in the past, is the default dataType isn't Json, so it doesn't pass it correctly. Might not be what's happening here though....

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert your data to json `JSON.stringify(result)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var model = @Html.Raw(Viewbag.MyJSON);

var viewModelDetails = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

this.addData = function() {
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModelDetails);
console.log(data);
$.post("/user/add", JSON.stringify(data), function(result){
//stuff
}, 
dataType: json,
traditional: true

);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced issues like this before.I share you the solution what i made.

**Make a change like below**

```
var data = ko.toJS(viewModelDetails);
```

**Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the json2.js library**

I know this will **work perfect**.If it **solves your problem** mark it as **answer**

If it is **useful to you** then click **uplink**

**Whats the problem in the code:-**

```
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModelDetails);
```

You need to parse **data** again as json , then you can use it, else it will get error.