# pass a object list view to controller with Ajax function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list object. I want to pass my list view to controller with Ajax function My code like :

```
    function Save()
    {
        debugger;
        if(!ValidateInput()) return;
        var oRecipe=RefreshObject();
        var oRecipeDetails=$('#tblRecipeDetail').datagrid('getRows');
        var postData = $.toJSON(oRecipe);
        var mydetailobj= $.toJSON(oRecipeDetails);
//        postData="Hello world!!!!!!! Faruk";
        //return;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/Recipe/Save',
            data: { myjsondata : postData, jsondetailobject : mydetailobj},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                oRecipe = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (oRecipe.ErrorMessage == '' || oRecipe.ErrorMessage == null) {
                    alert("Data Saved sucessfully");
                    window.returnValue = oRecipe;
                    window.close();
                }
                else {
                    alert(oRecipe.ErrorMessage);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }

        });
    }
```

Normally my code run successfully if my list length <=3/4 but when my list length >4 here a problem arise. I could not find out what is bug? please any one suggest me

Note : Here i try to pass by list object convert to JSON data

Comment: please give a example link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927576/controller-action-wont-bind-json-viewmodel/14927815#14927815

Comment: need any special jquery reference?

Comment: I think its pretty old

Comment: i get a message like JSON Undefine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why type "GET"? It is obvious that you want to post your data back to the controller. Change it to "POST" and try.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            ...
```